# R - multivariate normal distribution in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, multivariate-testing

I would like to simulate a multivariate normal distribution in R. I've seen I need the values of mu and sigma. Unfortunately, I don't know how obtain them.

In the following link you will find my data in a csv file "Input.csv". Thanks  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/blnr3jvius8f3eh/AACOhqyzZGiDHAOPmyE__873a?dl=0

Please, could you show me an example? Raúl

Comment: You have (a) a classification problem with (b) continuous and discrete variables in your data and (c) your classes are very very very unbalanced. I'd say you have three problems that have little to do with the multivariate Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Yes, I would like to use a mutivariate Gaussian distribution. Could you help on use it as a classifier with the provided data? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your link is broken, but I understand that you want to generate random samples from empirical multivariate normal distribution. You can do it like that, assuming `df` is your `data.frame` with data:

```
library('MASS')
Sigma <- var(df)
Means <- colMeans(df)
simulation <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, Means, Sigma)
```

Comment: Thanks @cyberj0g. It works. The link is up know. How can I use this function as classifier? Like a threshold.

Comment: Your dataset seem to have only features (input variables), without target variable. So you probably need clusterization, not classification? If so, try k-means algorithm.

Comment: I've add a new dataset "Input2.csv" with labels (6th column). Is it possible to do it with this technique?