# Multivariate Statistics and R

Tags: r, statistics, multivariate-testing

i am new with R and also in the area of Multivariate Statistics.
i would like to sample 100 samples from this normal dist

```
mu = (0,1,0)' 
cov = (16,1,1;1,16,2;1,2,16)
```

and the mission is to check the hypothesis with 5% conf whether matrix cov is Diagonal matrix or not.
also need to find the p-value.

the implementation should be in R

thanks

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Did you search for something like "sample from multivariate normal distribution"? When I did I got several possible duplicate questions, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30931828/903061) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13291308/903061). However, the code you've posted isn't valid syntax - if you need help defining vectors and matrices I would start with some of the introductory material [in the R tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Comment: i have been stuck after sampling the data from the given (mu,cov),
i am not sure which test to run Hotteling or Likelihood ratios,
(i am not sure also how to run those tests in R)

Comment: You should show the code you have, otherwise you will get answers (as below) providing what you already know. As for "what test should I run", that's a question better suited for stats.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Check the mvrnorm function from the MASS package.

```
library(MASS)

mu <- c(0,1,0)
cov <- matrix(c(16,1,1,1,16,2,1,2,16), ncol = 3)
random <- mvrnorm(n = 100, mu = mu, Sigma = cov)
```

With this code you should be able to draw the random numbers. I don't what you mean with testing the hypothesis...

Comment: How about instead of saying _this should help_ explain how this fixes the OPs issue.

Comment: what is the different between using mvrnorm and mvrnorm?